# How would I go about loading result sets from separate SQL Server Database queries into a GridView?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I have to accomplish what seemed like a pretty trivial task, but it has proven to be a bit more confusing than I anticipated. Here is the scenario:

I have a `GridView` that is getting data from my `SQL Server` database and displaying it on a web page (a pretty normal scenario). However, I have some filters that determine which query is run on the database, which obviously determines the data that is ultimately displayed in the `GridView`. I am having a bit of trouble incorporating these filters efficiently. Currently, I have these three subroutines: `LoadPendingRequests()`, `LoadApprovedRequests()`, and `LoadDeniedRequests()`. As you might expect, I have a `CheckboxList` that allows the user to choose "Pending," "Approved," or "Denied," and, depending on which is chosen, the corresponding subroutine is called, thus populating the `GridView` with the corresponding data. This part works.

The user has the option to load any combination of pending, denied, and approved requests at the same time, however. This is where I'm having trouble. Here is the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler for the `CheckboxList`:

```
Protected Sub CheckboxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckboxList1.SelectedIndexChanged

        If CheckboxList1.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
            CheckboxList1.SelectedIndex = 0
        End If


        If CheckboxList1.Items(0).Selected = True Then 'pending checkbox
            LoadPendingRequests()
        End If
        If CheckboxList1.Items(1).Selected = True Then 'approved checkbox
            LoadApprovedRequests()
        End If
        If CheckboxList1.Items(2).Selected = True Then 'denied checkbox
            LoadDeniedRequests()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Here is an example of the subroutines that load the requests (they're all the same, just replace the filter word in the "where" clause):

```
Protected Sub LoadPendingRequests()
            Try
                Dim DbConnection As New DevConnection()
                Dim Da As New SqlDataAdapter()

                Using DbConnection.Conn
                    DbConnection.Conn.Open()
                    Using SqlCmd As New SqlCommand()
                        With SqlCmd
                            .Connection = DbConnection.Conn
                            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                            .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.reqTable where Status = 'Pending'"
                        End With
                        Using Da
                            Da.SelectCommand = SqlCmd
                            Using Dt As New DataTable()
                                Da.Fill(Dt) 'populates the dataset
                                Gv.DataSource = Dt
                                'Gv.DataBind()

                                CheckSuggestionApprovalStatus()
                            End Using
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

    End Sub
```

How would I go about loading pending, approved, and denied requests at the same time when the user clicks on the boxes in the `CheckboxList`, given this setup? I am open to changing this process entirely if necessary.

Comment: The simplest way to approach this (although perhaps frowned upon by purists) is to have just one query in which the WHERE clause is built on the fly depending on the checked boxes.

Comment: @peterG Thanks for the reply. I thought of doing it this way, as well. I'd like to see if anyone has any ideas for an alternative approach, but I might end up doing it this way.

Comment: A better option would be to create a stored procedure that receives the status as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how a stored procedure for this type of thing might look.

```
create procedure Requests_GetByStatus
(
    @Status varchar(10)
) as
    set nocount on;

    select *
    from dbo.reqTable
    where Status = @Status
```

I would urge you to not store the status as text in every row. I would instead have a RequestStatus table that holds the text value and an int (likely an identity) and store that value in your Request table. And of course don't really use select *, you should specify the columns you actually need.

--EDIT--

This is one way you can pass in three parameters and get the data in any group in a single query. I have expanded the where predicates significantly so you can easily see what is happening.

```
create procedure Requests_GetByStatus
(
    @Pending bit = null
    , @Approved bit = null
    , @Denied bit = null
) as
    set nocount on;

    select *
    from dbo.reqTable
    where 
    (
        (
            Status = 'Pending' 
            AND
            @Pending = 1
        )
    )
    OR
    (
        (
            Status = 'Approved'
            AND
            @Approved = 1
        )
    )
    OR
    (
        (
            Status = 'Denied'
            AND
            @Denied = 1
        )
    )
```

Comment: I like this approach. Thanks for the suggestion. I am trying it now. Out of curiosity, why would you want the status to be stored in a separate table instead of the current approach? I'm interested to know. I'm not really a db guy.

Comment: Well let's say that business decides they no longer want the status to be "Denied". Instead they want to name it "Refused". If you store the description in every single row you have to update every single row. If it is a separate table you update that one row in your lookup table. Storing the text over and over is not well normalized. Consider if you have three locations that are inserting into that table and they all have to spell it the same. Then you find one that is spelled wrong...ugh.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. How does this approach help me load requests with different statuses at the same time? I'm sure I'm just missing something.

Comment: Ahh you want to be able to load any combination of them yeah? This requires a slight modification to the logic. I will post an update.

Comment: Thanks! I do like your idea, though. I am going to use the stored procedure to write one function on the server side, as opposed to three. I don't know why I didn't think of that...

Comment: Thanks for this! It worked exactly as I had hoped it would!